# Friedrichs/Poincare inequality on $S_n \times (0,\infty)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Should I expect the following Friedrichs/Poincare inequality to hold for $u \in C^\infty(S_n \times (0,\infty))$ with $u(x,0) = 0$:
$$\int_{S_n \times (0,\infty)}|u|^2 \leq C\int_{S_n \times (0,\infty)}{|\nabla u|^2}$$
where $S_n$ denotes the the hypersphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and I have used the trivial extension metric to define $\nabla$.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not in simple unbounded domains. Choose a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function $v$ on $(0, \infty)$ which vanishes at $0$ and which is identically $1$ on $(1,\infty)$, say. Extend $v$ to $u \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{S}^n \times (0,\infty))$ by setting $u(s,x) := v(x)$, with $s \in \mathbb{S}^n$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$.

Then the left-hand side of your inequality if infinite, while the right-hand side is finite.

Answer (score 2):

By Fubini's theorem and by taking functions that do not depend on the $\mathbb{S}^n$ variable, your estimate is equivalent with the inequality
$$
  \int_0^\infty \vert u \vert^2 \le C \int_0^\infty \vert u' \vert^2,
$$
which does not hold.

With a similar reasoning you have the Hardy inequality
$$
 \int_{\mathbb{S}^n \times(0,∞)} \frac{|u (x, t)|^2}{|t|^2} \,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d} t ≤4∫_{\mathbb{S}^n×(0,∞)} |∇u|^2,
$$
which might be useful.